# How can you get the intensity of a pixel in java?

Tags: java, image, colors, pixel, grayscale

I need to check the intensity of a pixel in a greyscale image in order to swap it with another pixel with similar intensity. At first i was calculating the average RGB color but I'm not sure this is the right thing to do.

Comment: what do you mean by "intensity"?

Comment: hokay, im guessing you dont even know yourself then